# How to localize OpenApi3 api definition to several languages?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have definition of my API as OpenAPI3 document and I'm using swagger UI as viewer. All "description" fields now on English. But I need to support API documentation for several languages (English and Russian for example).

How to localize OpenAPI3 document to several languages? Does some standard mechanism exist for that or the only possible way is to write my own custom solution for this problem?

Comment: _"write some bicycle solution"_ what does that even mean?

Comment: It means, that i should write my own custom solution for this problem, because standard mechanism doesn't exist

Comment: You should really avoid idioms like that, they are definitely not globally recognized.

Comment: Ok, sorry. i fixed question

Comment: Related discussion in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/274

Comment: Also related (or duplicate): [Localization for API Specs with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47716439/113116)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no answers or any solution into github discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this extension could be a solution (not tested): https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-i18n-extension

This, as I understand, requires additional re-translation of YAML file on the go with JS, so I am not sure it can work with Swagger UI seamlessly.